# Java code for system date dynamically and giving an alert

Tags: java

I am trying to write a java code that will give an alert at a specific time of day but I don't know why I am failing(Please be gentle to my questions as I am totally new to programming). I have this code

```
    new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1).schedule(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if(Calendar.SECOND==30)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hola Amigo");
        }
    }
}, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Should I try to refresh the page? Please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking that a fixed constant value `Calendar.SECOND` (`13`) equals `30`. Obviously, this will never be true so the dialog will never appear. You need to check this field in a `Calendar` *instance*.

Also using `schedule` means that the executor thread is only run once. Use `scheduleAtFixedRate`.

Also you would need to call `showMessageDialog` in the `EDT` to ensure that the call does not block the `Executor` `Thread`.

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int second = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        if (second == 30) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hola Amigo");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

If you want to call the `ExecutorService` every 30 seconds rather than repeatly checking the current second, you could call

```
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(myRunnable, 1, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```